# Swift 2.0 Call Can Throw but is not marked with try

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, xcode7

I'm trying to update the code in my app after the update to XCode 7 and it looks like I'm going to have to go through a serious learning curve again just to catch up. What am I doing wrong in the code below?

Is if let still being used?

[image]

I am so not familiar with try/catch outside of C#. I don't know how to use it in the context of swift and it'd be great to find an easy to understand guide that doesn't assume that I ever knew Objective C or have ever come across this before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...)
    return json
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("JSON Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Is the whole "if let" block gone in swift 2.0? Are we not using that anymore?

Comment: `if let` is still there but you were calling a throwable function. If you are sure the function call will succeed, you can use `if let json = try! NSJSONSerialization...`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a method that throws a Swift error and as such, it needs to be marked with try.

```
do
{
    let json = try NSJSONSerializer.JSONObjectWithData(...)
    return json
}
catch 
{
    // By default the catch clause defines the variable error as whatever ws thrown
    print("Error is \(error)")
    return nil
}
```

Is pretty much what you want.

Answer (score -1):

In case of my understanding is

```
let result: AnyObject? = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
```